# role postgres does not exist - attempting to connect to psql inside Express app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

There are similar questions with the one I have, but I'm still having trouble figuring out this issue.
I've added psql bin path to my bash_profile (on Mac) and I can run psql by:

```
psql -U postgres
```

The problem I have is that I can't run it inside my Express app. following the instructions on [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#postgresql) documentations, I have the following code:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
var pgp = require('pg-promise')();
var db = pgp(
    `postgres://
    ${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}
    @
    ${process.env.DB_HOST}:5432/${process.env.DB_DATABASE}`
);
module.exports = db;
```

Then I try to make the db connection in app.js by

```
var db = require('./models/dbConnection/postgres')
db.one('SELECT $1 AS value', 123)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('DATA:', data.value)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR:', error)
})
```

I have defined my environment variables in my *.env* file as follows:

```
DB_CONLIMIT=50
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
```

when I run the app, I get:

> [nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`   local-library:server Listening
> on port 3000 +0ms ERROR: error: role "
> postgres" does not exist
> at Parser.parseErrorMessage

looking at my user table in psql when I run it via terminal:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you user name has an embedded whitespace in it.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes, that was it. The way I have divided the db connection (var db) into multiple lines is not correct and is creating a new line character - feel free to leave an answer here so I can accept it as the resolution.

Comment: To avoid such environment config issue, it is better to just use a single `DB_CONNECTION` variable, with connection string, and consume it via [connection-string](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string).